# rdata: Some method to iterate through column names of a data frame?

Tags: r, rdata

I have about 30 lines of code that do just this (getting Z scores):

```
data$z_col1 <- (data$col1 - mean(data$col1, na.rm = TRUE)) / sd(data$col1, na.rm = TRUE)
data$z_col2 <- (data$col2 - mean(data$col2, na.rm = TRUE)) / sd(data$col2, na.rm = TRUE)
data$z_col3 <- (data$col3 - mean(data$col3, na.rm = TRUE)) / sd(data$col3, na.rm = TRUE)
data$z_col4 <- (data$col4 - mean(data$col4, na.rm = TRUE)) / sd(data$col4, na.rm = TRUE)
data$z_col5 <- (data$col5 - mean(data$col5, na.rm = TRUE)) / sd(data$col5, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Is there some way, maybe using `apply()` or something, that I can just essentially do (python):

```
for col in ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']:
    data{col} = ... z score code here
```

Thanks R friends.

Comment: You want to take a look at `colMeans` and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549762/is-there-such-colsd-in-r/17551217).

Answer (score 6):

A `data.frame` is a list, thus you can use `lapply`. Don't use `apply` on a `data.frame` as this will coerce to a `matrix`.

```
lapply(data, function(x) (x - mean(x,na.rm = TRUE))/sd(x, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Or you could use `scale` which performs this calculation on a vector.

```
lapply(data, scale)
```

---

You can translate the `python` style approach directy

```
for(col in names(data)){
   data[[col]] <- scale(data[[col]])
}
```

Note that this approach is not memory efficient in R as `[[<.data.frame` copies the entire data.frame each time.

Comment: Using lapply returned a list so to get back a data frame: data.frame(lapply(data, scale))

Answer (score 2):

I think you're right, apply() may be the way to go here.

For example:

```
data <- array(1:20, dim=c(4, 5))

data.zscores <- apply(data, 2, function(x)
    (x-mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))/sd(x, na.rm = TRUE))
```

The function apply() takes a matrix or array as it's first argument. The "2" refers to the dimension the function is iterated over - which in our case is columns. If we wanted to do it by row, we'd go with "1". Lastly, we have the function we want to apply to each column. See ?apply for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out
I iterate through the data frame to recognise NA rows

```
for(i in names(houseDF)){
  print(i)
  print(nrow(houseDF[is.na(houseDF[i]),]))
  print("---------------------")
}
```