# calculate column mean and sd when missing data is present

Tags: r

I want to calculate mean and sd from  column in dataframe. This column contain NA, and Inf value.

This is some example of value in this column

```
value

0.9343113   

0.8339523


0.0000000


NaN

Inf
```

I try to use apply function but it give an error message

```
mean=apply(am_bp$foldchange_so,2,FUN=function(x){mean(x,na.rm=T)})
```

> Error in apply(am_bp$foldchange_so, 2, FUN = function(x) { : 
>     dim(X) must have a positive length

Then I try `mean=colMeans(matrix(am_bp$foldchange_so),na.rm=TRUE)` but it give inf value

Moreover, I don't know how to calculate sd in the column

How should I solve this problem

Comment: What is the meaning of infinity in this case? You may want to look at `is.finite` but it's possible that infinity is the "correct" answer here.

Comment: why are you using `apply` or `colMeans` on a vector? Why not simply `mean(am_bp$foldchange_so, na.rm = TRUE)`?

Comment: There was recently a long discussion about `colSD` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549762/is-there-such-colsd-in-r), but it really doesn't look like you need it here.

Comment: It looks like you're new to `R`, so please take some time to study the R-intro manual and some of the online tutorials. It'll save you a lot of pain.

Comment: I already use mean(am_bp$foldchange_so, na.rm = TRUE) but it also give inf value which is not the answer I want