# How to get row wise standard deviation over specific columns

Tags: r

I am trying to get the standard deviation over specific columns in R. Unfortunately there doesnt seem to be a rowmeans type function so I am a bit lost. The dataset is as follows

```
chr      leftPos strand  JWA JWB JWC JWD OE33_F
chr1    100202137   +     2   0   1   0    0
chr1    100260304   -     141 62  75  55   20
chr1    100724039   -     0   1   0   0    0
```

and I would like to get the standard deviations for column headers JWA, JWB and JWD as follows. Please note that I dont think this question has been asked before as I am trying to get a simple standard deviation per row rather than as a column standard deviation. Also this is a dataframe which seems to make getting st dev from it a lot trickier than if it was a matrix.

```
 chr    leftPos   strand  JWA JWB JWC JWD OE33_F stdev
chr1    100202137   +     2   0   1   0    0     x
chr1    100260304   -     141 62  75  55   20    y
chr1    100724039   -     0   1   0   0    0     z
```

What can I use instead of rowmeans and how can I specify which columns I am interested in

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25099825/row-wise-variance-of-a-matrix-in-r/25100036#25100036) answer helps you?

Comment: No as this is a per row st dev im looking for and not per column. Also, getting standard deviations for a dataframe seems to be difficult (as opposed to a matrix).

Comment: The function there gives you per row variance. This is why it called `RowVar`....

Comment: Try to run `sqrt(RowVar(df[, c("JWA", "JWB", "JWD")]))`. Where `RowVar` is the function I provided a link to, and `df` is your data frame. It will give exactly what you need.

Comment: You state specifically, "I am trying to get the standard deviation over specific columns in R." and "... I would like to get the standard deviations for column headers JWA, JWB and JWD as follows."  And then you say you want it per row,  Please clarify what you want.

Comment: Just to clarify. The question asks to get the standard deviation per row for specific columns rather than for every value in the row

Comment: @user3632206, are you kidding me? Did you even try to run the code I've provided? It gives sd per row for the specific columns you want.

Comment: I was just answering Lance Roberts and hadn't got home yet to try your code David Arenburg- apologies for the confusion. I have run your code as follows > RowVar <- function(x) {
    +     rowSums((x - rowMeans(x))^2)/(dim(x)[2] - 1)
    + }
    > sqrt(RowVar(df[, c("JWA", "JWB", "JWD")]))
     Show Traceback
 
     Rerun with Debug
     Error in df[, c("JWA", "JWB", "JWD")] : 
      object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: Mr Arenburg- my apologies. It did in fact work a treat. The error I was getting was because I had defined my dataframe in a previous session and although it was displaying it it wasnt keeping it in memory. I tip my hat to your R wizadry. Thank you