# How to standardize data in r before running regressions in r?

Tags: r

So i have a data set with 48 obs and around 200 variables, my first column is my Date and the rest of the 199 variables are my x variables. So before I run my regression I would like to standardized them and remove outliers.

A simple version would be this so you get an idea :

```
data_final<- data.frame(
      Date1 =seq(as.Date('2017-01-01'), as.Date('2017-04-01'), by = 'months'),
      A = c(622,512,800,729),
      B = c(1,2,1,3),
      C = c(1,0,0,0),
      D = c(NA, NA, 0.3,0.2),
      E = c(300,200,100,200))
```

So I can find the SD of each column by doing:

```
dataSD<-data.frame(datafinal="sD",t(apply(datafinal[,-1],2,sd,na.rm=TRUE)))
```

And also standardize it with mean=0, sd=1 by using scale:

```
scale <- data.frame(Date = datafinal$Date1, scale(datafinal[2:ncol(datafinal)]))
```

Which all works, however, I want to see which outliers and any abnormal values in each of the 199 variables. More specifically I want to see which column has values that's 3 SD above its column mean.

Is there any way or suggestions you guys have to find a list or subset out these variables？

I'm thinking about something like subsetting:

```
[(abs(datafinal[2:ncol(datafinal)] - median(datafinal[2:ncol(datafinal)])) > 3*sd(datafinal[2:ncol(datafinal)]))])
```

But I'm not sure if it's the best way or if it works. I appreciate any inputs! Thanks in advance！

All the best,
Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of options to create a logical index indicating whether or not an outlier is detected. I've considered an outlier to be greater than 3 sds above the mean, as you have indicated (not checking for "lesser than").

Using `apply`, specifying the argument `margin=2` to apply the function column by column.

```
numericaldata <- datafinal[2:ncol(datafinal)]

apply(numericaldata, margin=2, function(x) {
  x>3 * sd(x, na.rm = TRUE) + mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
})%>%
cbind.data.frame(Date1=datafinal$Date1,.)
```

Using dplyr:

```
datafinal%>%
  mutate(across(.cols = 2:ncol(.), ~ . > 3 * sd(., na.rm = TRUE) + mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Results:

```
       Date1     A     B     C     D     E
1 2017-01-01 FALSE FALSE FALSE    NA FALSE
2 2017-02-01 FALSE FALSE FALSE    NA FALSE
3 2017-03-01 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
4 2017-04-01 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Should you want to know how many outliers were found, you can summarise the results like so:

```
results%>%
  summarise(across(2:ncol(.), ~sum(., na.rm=TRUE)))
```

Comment: You are right, 3 sd above not below , sorry for the typo! This is wonderful I love using dplyr, very clear and helpful! Thanks Dealec for you help! Much appreciated

Comment: Happy to help ! Yes, the new dplyr release (1.0) is pretty awesome.

Answer (score 2):

You could calculate `colMeans` and [`colSdColMeans`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17551600/6574038) and create a matrix based on 3*SDs.

```
means <- colMeans(data_final[-1], na.rm=TRUE)
sds <- colSdColMeans(data_final[-1])
(xd <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(c(-1, 1), function(x) x*3*sds*means))))
#           A         B      C           D         E
# 1 -251518.1 -5.026492 -0.375 -0.05303301 -48989.79
# 2  251518.1  5.026492  0.375  0.05303301  48989.79
```

Then, in an `mapply` look up if `any` of the column values are not `between` those ranges.

```
mapply(function(x, y) any(sapply(x, function(z)
  !data.table::between(z, y[1], y[2])), na.rm=TRUE), data_final[-1], xd)
#     A     B     C     D     E 
# FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Note, that if there are columns with all `NA` we probably need take special care by exception handling.

Comment: Great idea! And thanks for the heads up, I will subset the columns with NA out first! Thanks jay!