# How to calculate standard deviation per row?

Tags: r, standard-deviation

I am trying to calculate a standard deviation per row

The example of the input (`values_for_all`):

```
1  0.35 0.35 4.33 0.09 4.17 0.16 9.90 15.25 0.16 2.38 2.55 8.14 0.16 NA 0.16
2  8.75 3.22 7.34 0.56 2.43 0.23 1.20 8.45 1.26 NA NA 1.24 0.16 2.34 0.36
```

Code:

```
values_for_all[values_for_all == ''] <- NA
values_for_all[] <- lapply(values_for_all, as.numeric)
values_mean <- rowMeans(values_for_all, na.rm=TRUE) 

#calculating standard deviation per row 
SD <- rowSds(values_for_all, na.rm=TRUE)
SD
```

The first part (`values_mean`) works perfectly. Unfortunately, the part with `SD` doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apply` [lets you apply a function to all rows of your data](http://www.modernstatisticswithr.com/progchapter.html#a-first-example-with-apply):

```
apply(values_for_all, 1, sd, na.rm = TRUE)
```

To compute the standard deviation for each column instead, replace the `1` by `2`.

Comment: This is around 20% slower though than `matrixStats::rowSds`, ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17551600/6574038

Comment: @jay.sf That may well be true. `sd` and `mean` aren't very fast as they perform a lot of checks, traverse the data twice to lower the risk of errors due to floating point arithmetics, etc. If speed is a big concern other solutions can definitely be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `matrixStats` which implies that the function should be applied to matrices. Hence wrap `as.matrix` around your data frame.

```
matrixStats::rowSds(as.matrix(dat), na.rm=TRUE)
# [1] 4.515403 3.050903
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply`:

```
apply(df, 1, sd)
```